# What Pandas data type is passed to transform or apply in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

When trying to debug `groupby` function applications, [someone suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670726/computing-diffs-in-pandas-after-using-groupby-leads-to-unexpected-result/20671057?noredirect=1#comment30952282_20671047) that I use a dummy function to "see what is being passed" into the function for each group.  Sure, I'm game:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0) # so we can all play along at home

categories = list('abc')
categories = categories * 4
data_1 = np.random.randn(len(categories))
data_2 = np.random.randn(len(categories))

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': categories, 'data_1': data_1, 'data_2': data_2})

def f(x):
    print type(x)
    return x

print 'single column transform'
df.groupby(['category'])['data_1'].transform(f)
print '\n'

print 'single column (nested) transform'
df.groupby(['category'])[['data_1']].transform(f)
print '\n'

print 'multiple column transform'
df.groupby(['category'])[['data_1', 'data_2']].transform(f)

print '\n'
print '\n'

print 'single column apply'
df.groupby(['category'])['data_1'].apply(f)
print '\n'

print 'single column (nested) apply'
df.groupby(['category'])[['data_1']].apply(f)
print '\n'

print 'multiple column apply'
df.groupby(['category'])[['data_1', 'data_2']].apply(f)
```

This puts the following into my standard output:

```
single column transform
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


single column (nested) transform
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>


multiple column transform
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>




single column apply
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>


single column (nested) apply
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>


multiple column apply
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

So it seems like:

- Transform

  - Single column: 3 `Series`
  - Single column (nested): 2 `Series` and 3 `DataFrame`
  - Multiple columns: 3 `Series` and 3 `DataFrame`
- Apply

  - Single column: 3 `Series`
  - Single column (nested): 4 `DataFrame`
  - Multiple columns: 4 `DataFrame`

What's going on here?  Can anyone explain why each of these 6 calls is leading to the series of objects described above being passed to the function specified?

Comment: not 2 expand your question (which when fully answered would be a nice addition to the docs); need the cases where you have 2 groupers in the groupy (I don't the inputs t different but they do included the indexes on the objects being grouped)

Comment: I find I've had lots of questions of this type while trying to learn Pandas over the past month.  Are there good resources for this sort of thing?  I.e. general "here's how pandas is working under the hood" at the level of intuition building as opposed to hard-core source-code diving/rewriting?

Comment: under the hood generally requires you to construct and example then step thru the code. some is straightforward but a lot like groupby/indexing is not as it handles a lot of cases and data types. resources are the docs/cookbook, Wes's book and SO questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GroupBy.transform` will try fast_path and slow_path for your function.

- fast_path: call your function with a DataFrame object
- slow_path: call your function with `DataFrame.apply` function

When the result of fast_path is the same as slow_path, it will choose the fast_path.

the following output means that it finally selected the fast_path:

```
multiple column transform
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Here is the code link:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby.py#L2277

**Edit**

to inspect the calling stack:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0) # so we can all play along at home

categories = list('abc')
categories = categories * 4
data_1 = np.random.randn(len(categories))
data_2 = np.random.randn(len(categories))

df = pd.DataFrame({'category': categories, 'data_1': data_1, 'data_2': data_2})

import traceback
import inspect
import itertools

def f(x):
    flag = True
    stack = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x:"#stop here" not in x, 
                                traceback.format_stack(inspect.currentframe().f_back))
    print "*"*20
    print x
    print type(x)
    print
    print "\n".join(stack)
    return x

df.groupby(['category'])[['data_1', 'data_2']].transform(f) #stop here
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why there are more than 3 lines of "types" for each of my examples.  For my dataset, there are exactly 3 groups.  I would expect each example to contain exactly 3 of **something**...i.e. whatever Pandas finally picks and asks the function to process.  But that doesn't seem compatible with the output above.  Last 2 cases each operate on 4 DataFrames and nothing else?  Can you explain what's going on there?

Comment: @DJ_8one6, you can print the calling stack, and analyze what's going on.

Comment: Is there any way to force transform to pass the multi-column dataframe (i.e. not the individual series from the columns) to the function? I basically want the same behavior of `apply(my_func, axis =1)` but forcing it to return a result with the same index (i.e. what transform is supposed to do, but rather than working column by column, I want to be able to access multiple columns at the same time).