# Wrong number of items passed - Pandas and Transform

Tags: python, pandas, transform

Good Morning,

I have the following dataframe:

```
print(df)

a    b    
1    6   
1    4   
4    5
4    2
...
```

And I would like to get:

```
print(final_df)

    a    b   c 
    1    6   2
    1    4   2
    4    5   3
    4    2   3
    ...
```

I tried using:

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("a")["b"].transform(np.diff)
```

And it works of a small test set with two rows, but whenever I try to run in on the whole dataset, it returns:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1
```

How can I create *final_df* ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; your example works fine for me (though `c` is negative). You're suggesting that more than 2 rows this fails? Please give the full traceback.

Comment: Exactly; when I run it on the full 580-lines dataset, it returns that error

Comment: `numpys` `diff` will not work for you here. How about : `df["c"] = df.groupby("a")["b"].diff().abs().fillna(0)`

Comment: Ok, but can you please give the full traceback? 580 lines is not a huge amount to eye-ball on your side; are there any values in those columns that might be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem explained I guess:
[diff vs np.diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670726/computing-diffs-in-pandas-after-using-groupby-leads-to-unexpected-result)

And this might give you want you want:

```
df["c"] = df.groupby("a")["b"].diff().abs().fillna(0)
```

Comment: It does not act as transform, since it does not create the same value on grouped-by columns; nonetheless, I manage to solve my issue with your piece of code; Thanks