# Why the groupby.diff is so slower?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to compute diff of a series per each group, something as following example:

```
In [24]: rnd_ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5000))
    ...: com_ser = pd.concat([rnd_ser] * 500, keys=np.arange(500), names=['Date', 'ID'])

In [25]: d1 = com_ser.groupby("Date").diff()

In [26]: d2 = com_ser - com_ser.groupby("Date").shift()

In [27]: np.allclose(d1.fillna(0), d2.fillna(0))
Out[27]: True
```

There are two ways to solve this problem, however, the first one has badly performance:

```
In [30]: %timeit d1 = com_ser.groupby("Date").diff()
616 ms ± 5.62 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [31]: %timeit d2 = com_ser - com_ser.groupby("Date").shift()
95 ms ± 326 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is this expected or a bug?

The details of my env:

```
In [23]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.7.1.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.23.4
pytest: 3.9.3
pip: 18.1
setuptools: 40.5.0
Cython: 0.29
numpy: 1.15.3
scipy: 1.1.0
pyarrow: None
xarray: None
IPython: 7.1.1
sphinx: 1.8.1
patsy: 0.5.1
dateutil: 2.7.5
pytz: 2018.7
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.4.4
numexpr: 2.6.8
feather: None
matplotlib: 3.0.1
openpyxl: 2.5.9
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: 1.3.0
xlsxwriter: 1.1.2
lxml: 4.2.5
bs4: 4.6.3
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.2.12
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.10
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I am seeing similar numbers on my machine

```
%timeit d1 = com_ser.groupby("Date").diff()
523 ms ± 32.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit d2 = com_ser - com_ser.groupby("Date").shift()
80.8 ms ± 2.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Pandas implementation of `diff()` seems to be slow with the `groupby()`

For example if I make one **big series**

`big_ser = pd.Series(np.random.randn(int(1e7)))`

then compare a shift and subtract versus the `Series.diff()`

```
%timeit big_ser - big_ser.shift()
46.3 ms ± 789 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit big_ser.diff()
41.6 ms ± 488 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Then the times are identical between the implementations.  This follows, as you look the internal source code for `Series.diff`  it says explicitly in the comments

```
def diff(arr, n, axis=0):
    """
    difference of n between self,
    analogous to s-s.shift(n)
```

So I think its gotta be some overhead in the `groupby` specific to `diff()`

Comment: I have seen similar things like this " For some reason .groupby with .diff uses heaps of memory and it's all rather inefficient "   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670726/computing-diffs-in-pandas-after-using-groupby-leads-to-unexpected-result