# Python - Pandas - Unroll / Remove Cumulative Sum

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like the following (specific data below, this is generic). The no gives me a cumulative sum:

```
                 no
name day           
Jack Monday      10
     Tuesday     40
     Wednesday   90
Jill Monday      40
     Wednesday  150
```

I want to "unroll" the cumulative sum to give me something like this:

```
print df
   name        day   no
0  Jack     Monday   10
1  Jack    Tuesday   30
2  Jack  Wednesday   50
3  Jill     Monday   40
4  Jill  Wednesday  110
```

In essence, I'd like to do something like the following, but in reverse:
[Pandas groupby cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum)

Comment: How many indices are there here

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, but I cleaned up my file and reran your code and now it worked. I removed mention to any errors for clarity of the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do the following:

```
In [103]:
df.groupby(level=0).diff().fillna(df).reset_index()

Out[103]:
   name        day     no
0  Jack     Monday   10.0
1  Jack    Tuesday   30.0
2  Jack  Wednesday   50.0
3  Jill     Monday   40.0
4  Jill  Wednesday  110.0
```

So `groupby` the first index level and call `diff` to calculate the inter row differences per group and fill the `NaN` values with the original df values and call `reset_index`

Comment: @AmiTavory yes I thought I would get negative values, I'll remove it

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and code that demonstrates the problem and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method based on zip. It creates two series, the 2nd being offset by 1, and subtracts the difference between the two.

```
[n-nn for n,nn in zip(df['No'],df['No'][1:]+[0])]
```