# Calculating Non-Cumulative into a new column from cumulative values (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My goal is to convert below - Current Data Output

[image]

By adding a new column called Cases which is non-cumulative for further analysis.

I have tried this solution but I am not sure what is my mistake -

```
Data["Cases"] = Data.groupby(level=0).diff().fillna(Data).reset_index()
```

Please advise

Comment: @EdChum
answered a similar question but i couldn't adapt -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36452024/python-pandas-unroll-remove-cumulative-sum

Comment: Also now trying Data['Cases']  = Data.groupby(level=0).diff().fillna('Cumulative_Cases').reset_index()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach will be to take the lag of values in cumulative column and then calculating the difference between cumulative and lag.

```
import pandas as pd

date = ['2020-03-01','2020-03-02','2020-03-03','2020-03-04','2020-03-05'] 
cases = [1, 2, 4, 7, 10]
data = list(zip(date, cases))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date','Cases'])
df['Lag'] = df.Cases.shift(1).fillna(0)
df['Daily Cases'] = df.Cases - df.Lag

print(df)
         Date  Cases  Lag  Daily Cases
0  2020-03-01      1  0.0          1.0
1  2020-03-02      2  1.0          1.0
2  2020-03-03      4  2.0          2.0
3  2020-03-04      7  4.0          3.0
4  2020-03-05     10  7.0          3.0
```

Just remember that order is important here. So sort your cumulative column in ascending order.

*Don't forget to mark this as accepted answer if it helps you*