# Difference between tables

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary, set

I have two list of dictionaries representing the rows of two tables, so:

```
tableA = [{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}]

tableB = [{"id": 1, "name": "bar"}, {"id": 3, "name": "baz"}]
```

I want to obtain the difference in the following way:

```
added = [{"id": 3, "name": "baz"}]

updated = [{"id": 1, "name": "bar"}]
```

I know, that `id` is unique.

So, I am planning to loop over `tableB`, ask for the `id`, if they are equal then compare the dicts to know if it is `updated`, if not the id is new and it is `added`.

```
for x in tableA:
    idexists = false
    for y in tableY:
        if x["id"] == y["id"]:
           if x != y:
              updated.append(x)
           idexists = true
    if not idexists:
        added.append(x)
```

Is it correct? Can it be done in pythonic way?

Comment: It's unclear for me how's `added` and `updated` are calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *restructure* the tables into a more conveninent form of `id`: `name` dictionaries and then [diff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165352/771848):

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff


tableA = [{"id": 1, "name": "foo"}, {"id": 2, "name": "bar"}]

tableB = [{"id": 1, "name": "bar"}, {"id": 3, "name": "baz"}]

tableA = {item["id"]: item["name"] for item in tableA}
tableB = {item["id"]: item["name"] for item in tableB}

print(DeepDiff(tableA, tableB))
```

Prints:

```
{
  'dictionary_item_added': {'root[3]'}, 
  'dictionary_item_removed': {'root[2]'}, 
  'values_changed': {
    'root[1]': { 
      'old_value': 'foo', 
      'new_value': 'bar'
    }
  }
}
```

For calculating the differences used `deepDiff` module suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079022/771848), but you can use any of the suggested solutions from the linked thread.

---

Another idea could be to transform the list of dictionaries into a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and then diff:

- [Outputting difference in two Pandas dataframes side by side - highlighting the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)
- [Computing diffs within groups of a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648346/computing-diffs-within-groups-of-a-dataframe)

Comment: Great! But the thing is, there woule be more columns than just `name`, would it be efficient? because the tables are large. (Now I will take a look to pandas)

Comment: @FacundoGFlores please measure to find if this would be more efficient in your case on a large table. The big advantage of re-structuring is that we have is the constant-time lookups by `id`. Note that we lose order in this case (assuming it is not significant)..