# Pandas groupby multiple fields then diff

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

So my dataframe looks like this:

```
         date    site country  score
0  2018-01-01  google      us    100
1  2018-01-01  google      ch     50
2  2018-01-02  google      us     70
3  2018-01-03  google      us     60
4  2018-01-02  google      ch     10
5  2018-01-01      fb      us     50
6  2018-01-02      fb      us     55
7  2018-01-03      fb      us    100
8  2018-01-01      fb      es    100
9  2018-01-02      fb      gb    100
```

Each `site` has a different score depending on the `country`. I'm trying to find the 1/3/5-day difference of `score`s for each `site`/`country` combination.

Output should be:

```
          date    site country  score  diff
8  2018-01-01      fb      es    100   0.0
9  2018-01-02      fb      gb    100   0.0
5  2018-01-01      fb      us     50   0.0
6  2018-01-02      fb      us     55   5.0
7  2018-01-03      fb      us    100  45.0
1  2018-01-01  google      ch     50   0.0
4  2018-01-02  google      ch     10 -40.0
0  2018-01-01  google      us    100   0.0
2  2018-01-02  google      us     70 -30.0
3  2018-01-03  google      us     60 -10.0
```

I first tried sorting by `site`/`country`/`date`, then grouping by `site` and `country` but I'm not able to wrap my head around getting a difference from a grouped object.

Comment: how to i get StringIO for python3? I am trying to recreate your problem

Comment: @JulianRachman use `io`

Comment: ok hang on i am trying to recreate your problem

Comment: @Alex @ayhan I've edited the expected output. Essentially, `es` and `gb` would appear before `us`.

Comment: @Craig for that you could add `df.sort_values(by=['site', 'country', 'date'], ascending=[False, True, True])` with @ayhan 's answer

Answer (score 77, accepted):

First, sort the DataFrame and then all you need is `groupby.diff()`:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['site', 'country', 'date'])

df['diff'] = df.groupby(['site', 'country'])['score'].diff().fillna(0)

df
Out: 
         date    site country  score  diff
8  2018-01-01      fb      es    100   0.0
9  2018-01-02      fb      gb    100   0.0
5  2018-01-01      fb      us     50   0.0
6  2018-01-02      fb      us     55   5.0
7  2018-01-03      fb      us    100  45.0
1  2018-01-01  google      ch     50   0.0
4  2018-01-02  google      ch     10 -40.0
0  2018-01-01  google      us    100   0.0
2  2018-01-02  google      us     70 -30.0
3  2018-01-03  google      us     60 -10.0
```

`sort_values` doesn't support arbitrary orderings. If you need to sort arbitrarily (google before fb for example) you need to store them in a collection and set your column as categorical. Then sort_values will respect the ordering you provided there.

Comment: For whatever reason, the line above kept throwing errors like `TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'`. However this worked: `df.groupby(['site', 'country'])['score'].transform(pd.Series.diff).fillna(0)`.

Comment: @JohanDettmar the reason for that exception was because you were calling `diff()` on a Series, which has only a single column, not a DataFrame. The Series `diff()` doesn't have an `axis` parameter, because there's only a single axis.

Comment: Why am I not also grouping by date? Does diff recognize the date? I don't find anything regarding the automatic detection of a date https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html

Comment: @Auss Because we are trying to find the differences between these values on different dates. If we also group by dates, each group would have a single observation. Instead, we need multiple observations in each group (for different dates) so that we can find the differences between the values for those dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can shift and substract grouped values:

```
df.sort_values(['site', 'country', 'date'], inplace=True)

df['diff'] = df['score'] - df.groupby(['site', 'country'])['score'].shift()
```

Result:

```
         date    site country  score  diff
8  2018-01-01      fb      es    100   NaN
9  2018-01-02      fb      gb    100   NaN
5  2018-01-01      fb      us     50   NaN
6  2018-01-02      fb      us     55   5.0
7  2018-01-03      fb      us    100  45.0
1  2018-01-01  google      ch     50   NaN
4  2018-01-02  google      ch     10 -40.0
0  2018-01-01  google      us    100   NaN
2  2018-01-02  google      us     70 -30.0
3  2018-01-03  google      us     60 -10.0
```

To fill `NaN` with `0` use `df['diff'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`.