# Zipcodes with a cumulative column over time: add column that contains the added value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that consists of zipcodes, with a quarter and a cumulative number.
This number contains all the events that happened in that zipcode up and including that quarter.
I want to add a column, e.g., 'new', that notes the change in events in that quarter.
My current dataframe looks like this:

```
Zipcode      Quarter       Cumulative_number
9999         2020 Q1             1
9999         2020 Q2             1
9999         2020 Q3             2
9999         2020 Q4             3
2000         2018 Q2             0
2000         2018 Q3             4
2000         2018 Q4             0
```

Ideally the dataframe would look like this:

```
Zipcode      Quarter       Cumulative_number     New
9999         2020 Q1             1                0    
9999         2020 Q2             1                0
9999         2020 Q3             2                1
9999         2020 Q4             3                1
2000         2018 Q2             0                0
2000         2018 Q3             4                4
2000         2018 Q4             4                0
```

The code used to create the cumulative number looks like this:

```
df = (df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.columns.min(), until, freq='QS', name='Quarter'), axis=1)
        .ffill(axis=1)
        .stack()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='Cumulative_number'))
```

Comment: how is the cumulative number = 0 for zip code 2000 and quarter 2018 Q4?

Comment: Thanks, this was a mistake in the mock-up data frame. I updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can sort according to zip code and quarter.
Then get the diff between quarters after grouping by zip code.
Finally, assign value 0 to the first value in every zip code.

```
df.sort_values(['Zipcode', 'Quarter'], inplace=True)
df['diffs'] = df.groupby('Zipcode')['Cumulative_number'].diff()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

NOTE that Im assuming 2018 Q4 should be 4 not 0 logically.

```
    Zipcode Quarter Cumulative_number   diffs
0   9999    2020 Q1 1   0.0
1   9999    2020 Q2 1   0.0
2   9999    2020 Q3 2   1.0
3   9999    2020 Q4 3   1.0
4   2000    2018 Q2 0   0.0
5   2000    2018 Q3 4   4.0
6   2000    2018 Q4 4   0.0
```

Answer inspired by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648346/computing-diffs-within-groups-of-a-dataframe) so if you want alternatives can check this link out.