# date difference along with group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe which consist of order_date,order_time for multiple restaurant. I want to create a new column which would calculate the queue based on order date and time.

[image]

I have tried using diff() on order time along with group by on order_date and restaurant_id but it didnt worked.

Expected output : a new column 'time_diff' which would contain difference between consecutive orders for same restaurant and on same date.

Comment: So for the first two order times in your example, you want a new column with the result of `47:19.1 - 46:67.9` ?

Comment: @Nick , Yes if the order belong to same restaurant and is of same date.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62330004/2570277) answer solve the problem?

Comment: @nick, No since I have to sort data based on restaurant id, order date and order date. Then i need to calculate the time difference.